# How to check if some number can be expressed as x^y if number is a decimal?

Tags: algorithm, math

I was asked this question in a coding interview.

We can derive whether a number can be expressed in x^y using log or prime factors or other ways if that number is an integer like 16, 25, 100. 
But what if the number is 0.4 or 0.002 or any other decimal number, how to approach this situation.

Please help me find an approach. Thanks :)

Comment: Are there any restrictions on `x` and on `y`? If not, just use `a^1` where `a` is the desired result. The problem becomes more interesting if `x` and `y` must be integers; another variant is is `x` must be rational and `y` must be an integer.

Comment: I suspect x and y either have to be *integers* or *rational* / *fractions*. Can you tell us if that is the case?

Comment: "just use a^1 where a is the desired result". Sorry, I didn't understand this part.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @arbuthnott, for now let's assume x and y are integers and also y < 0 is possible.

Comment: pragmaticpi: When dealing with tricky questions like these, it is very important to use a precise language. Suppose the question is "Can 0.002 be written in the form x^y?". I interpret this as "Is there a pair of two real numbers x and y such that x^y = 0.002?" and the answer is trivially "Yes, for instance x = 0.002 and y = 1 (because x^y = 0.002^1 = 0.002)." And the answer "yes" is true for all numbers, not only 0.002. Therefore, the function you are looking for is something like this: `function IsPower(x: double): boolean; begin result := true; end`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: This question is a continuation of the common question of determining if a positive integer can be written as the integral power of an integer, *using computer programming*. The programming restriction means it is answered differently from a math question. My answer, especially the second half, dealt with the question in that way. So I do not see this question as off-topic. The initial version was unclear, but that was cleared up in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is an integer and `y` is a non-negative integer, `x^y` is an integer (if we leave out the ambiguous case `0^0`). If we allow `y` to be a negative integer, then `x^y` is also expressed as `1/ (x^(-y))` which is the reciprocal of a non-negative integer (if we leave out the undefined cases of `0^-1` etc.).

So, if your given value of `x^y` is not an integer, check its reciprocal. That must be an integer and decomposable into `x^y` for integral `x` and `y`.

I assume here that `x` and `y` must be integers. If not, you could use `a^1` where `a` is the desired result. For example, if you are given `0.4`, you could use `0.4^1`. But if we have the integer restrictions on `x` and `y`, you see `0.4` is not an integer, and neither is `2.5`, its reciprocal. So this cannot be decomposed. Give `0.002` we try its reciprocal `500` then see its only decomposition is `500^1`, so the only decomposition of `0.002` is `500^-1`.

---

If I were asked this question in a coding interview, I would bring up one more point. Some numbers, such as `0.002`, cannot be represented exactly in a standard floating-point variable. So taking its reciprocal may not result in an integer, even when that is expected. That is true, for example, for `x=1/49`: taking its reciprocal in Python 3.6.4 does not give `49`. A better example is `x=0.00016`. Its reciprocal should be `6250` but it actually is `6249.999999999999`. So decomposing these numbers is more difficult. This affects how the number is input to the routine. In Python, for example, best results are gotten when the "decimal number" is not input as a float value, but rather as a string or as a Decimal value from the `decimal` module or a Fraction value from the `fractions` module. That keeps the value of the decimal number exact, and the routine can properly check if the reciprocal is an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but what if y can be less than 0. For example, 0.5 can be expressed as 2^-1.

Comment: @pragmaticpi: That is exactly what I dealt with in my answer (but I see I forgot to add one thing--I just added it; thanks for the reminder). Since `0.5` is not an integer, we look at its reciprocal, namely `2`. The only way to decompose that is `2^1`. Therefore we take the negative of the exponent and see that the decomposition of `0.5` is `2^-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x, y need to be integers, you could do it as:

Lets take example of `0.25`

Rewrite it as `25*10^(-2)`

Now write `25 as 5^2`

Now you have

```
0.25 = (5^2)(10^-2)
                  = ((5^-1)^(-2))(10^-2)
                  = ((5^-1)*(10))^-2
                  = 2^-2
```

this is possible if you have equal powers ( absolute value ) for 5, 10.

Another example:

```
0.5 = ( 5^1 )* ( 10^-1)
                       = (( 5^-1)^-1)*(10^-1)
                       = ((5^-1)*(10))^-1
                       = 2^-1
```

So one way to do it is first see if you can write the number after decimal and zeros e.g. 25 in 0.25, 8 in 0.008 which is actually called "mantissa" of a real number as x^y - then if that y in x^y is equal to 10's power in absolute value, you could write it as x^y where x, y are integers with y as negative.

Comment: what do you mean by 10's power in absolute value?

Comment: for 0.25 when you write it as 5^2*10^-2 : the power of 5, 10 are 2, -2, so the absolute value i.e. |2| or |-2| is the same.

Comment: In that case, let's take 0.16, it can be represented as 2^4 and 4^2. If I take 2^4, then their absolute values are not the same but if I take 4^2, then according to your logic it will lead to 2.5^-2. So, is it expressable or not?

Comment: Well if you let x to be not just an integer, then yes it is possible to express as 2.5^-2, if  x and y are constrained to be integers, then I cannot think of a way of expressing 0.16 as x ^ y.

Comment: I will try to implement it in java taking x as an integer. Thanks a lot for the approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 10^y repeatedly until the number becomes an integer. This amounts to moving the decimal point by y places repeatedly until after the last significant digit.

E.g.

0.4 => 40: not square

0.00002 => 0.002 => 0.2 => 20: not square

0.0081 => 0.81 => 81: square

Comment: What about numbers like `1/9` or `0.111111111111111`?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: you multiply by 10^∞ and take the square root.